# Process Builder Entry Criteria Formula

Tags: process-builder, isblank, entry-criteria

I have the following entry criteria in the Process Builder

```
!ISBLANK([Material_Request__c].Out__c.Email_Address__c )&&
   NOT(ISBLANK([Material_Request__c].Out__c) )&&
     [Material_Request__c].Returnable_Flag__c == true &&
       !ISBLANK([Material_Request__c].Return_Date__c)
```

The problem with this is that the Process builder is not supposed to execute when `material_request__c.out__c` is null. 
However, this is not happening and it is entering the **Execution Actions** and throwing an error. 
I have tried various permutation combinations of NOT(ISBLANK([Material_Request__c].Out__c) ).

Material_Request__c].Out__c is a lookup field

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `ISNULL` instead?

Comment: I did try isnull. It is still not working.

Comment: try to do !ISBLANK([Material_Request__c].Out__c) validation prior to !ISBLANK([Material_Request__c].Out__c.Email_Address__c)

Comment: You are a life saver. Thanks @Oleksiy. Please put this as answer so that I can accept this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do !ISBLANK([Material_Request__c].Out__c) validation **prior to** any field validation(s) from this related record:

```
[Material_Request__c].Returnable_Flag__c &&
!ISBLANK([Material_Request__c].Return_Date__c) &&
!ISBLANK([Material_Request__c].Out__c) &&
!ISBLANK([Material_Request__c].Out__c.Email_Address__c)
```